# increase color depth in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: intel-graphics, color-depth

May sound weird, but please continue reading
 
On my Ubuntu 14.04, I have color depth of 24 as show by `xwininfo -root | grep Depth`
On windows I have color depth of 32bit. Why its less on Ubuntu ? Can I increase color depth to 32 ?

Hardware details:
Intel i5 2450m processor
integrated graphics Intel HD3000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"32-bit color" is generally a misnomer in regard to display color depth. While actual 32-bit color at ten to eleven bits per channel produces over 4.2 billion distinct colors, the term “32-bit color” is most often a misuse referring to 24-bit color images with an additional eight bits of non-color data (I.E.: alpha, Z or bump data), or sometimes even to plain 24-bit data.

[Source](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/how-set-color-depth-to-32-in-gnome-815805/)

Comment: so you mean I dont have to worry as its already 32bit or i can increase it ?

Comment: It is the same thing. In Windows it is represented as 32(8R+8G+8B+8Alpha) and in Ubuntu it is represented as 24(8R+8G+8B). Ultimately, the RGB values are of an 8-bit depth each.

Comment: `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` -- on my system I dont have this file. for other answer in which they showed how to change color depth from 16 to 24, this file was must

Comment: I don't have the file either but as I previously stated, it is a difference in the representation, ie RGBA vs RGB. The depth per channel is still 8bit.

Comment: I agree. "24-bit color" means 8 bit color, no extra bytes. "32-bit color" means 8 bit color, one padding byte to allow each pixel to start at even byte offset. Some hardware only supports one or the other, some hardware supports both but may have better performance with one or the other. If you're happy with the performance, there's no need to change between "24" or "32" bit colors. The "30-bit color" or 10 bits per channel is different mode and actually improves color quality if your display really supports it. Most displays accept the *signal* but only have 24 bit panels.